# Problemas ao realizar o "push" no Git

Tags: git, github

Estou fazendo um curso de Git/GitHub. Porém, quando tento dar o meu primeiro "Push" o terminal me pede meu nome de usuário e senha, ao adicionar as informações, me deparo com o seguinte erro no retorno:

> Username for 'https://github.com': ysbrandao Password for
> 'https://ysbrandao@github.com':  remote: Support for password
> authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal
> access token instead. remote: Please see
> https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for
> 'https://github.com/YsBrandao/DIO-Desafio-github-primeiro-repositorio.git/'

Print do terminal para melhor visualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: olá Yago, leu a mensagem de erro? *"Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead"* ou seja  precisa de um token no lugar na password. Pode gerar o token logando no github

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Obrigado pelo comentário. Eu estava estranhando essa mensagem justamente por ja ter feito todo o procedimento de "tokenização". enfim, resolvi gerando um novo token SSH e excluindo o antigo. Deve ter ocorrido algum erro no processo de credenciamento no meu ambiente.  Consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Autenticação via `https` foi desabilitada do GitHub em 13 de Agosto de 2021. Conforme esta [`postagem do blog`](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Para resolver este problema é necessário trocar o seu método de autenticação para `chave SSH` ou `token`.

Para fazer esta configuração é necessário fazer o login no Github e Adicionar uma nova chave privada à sua conta. Se não possui uma chave SSH gerada, o GitHub possui um tutorial que ensina a gerar esta chave. [`Ref`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Para isto basta acessar seu perfil no GitHub (estar logado):

1. Configurações (settings)
2. Chaves SSH e GPG
3. clicar no botão `Nova chave SSH`
4. Adicione sua chave

Após estes passos é necessário configurar o seu repositório (o repositório que está em sua máquina), para fazer o acesso via chave ssh:

1. acessar o diretório do repositório
2. executar o comando: `git remote -v`
3. Como está recebendo um erro 403 provavelmente a saída será algo do tipo:

   ```
   origin https://github.com/<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git (fetch)
   origin https://github.com/<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git (fetch)
   #       ⇑
   ```

O que é necessário prestar atenção é a parte do `https`, agora basta remover esta origin e adicionar a que utiliza chave ssh.

Para isso basta executar o seguinte comando (estou assumindo que está no repositório que está com o erro 403).

```
 git remote remove origin
 git remote add origin git@github.com:<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git
 #                                         ⇑              ⇑
```

Trocar os valores das variáveis `seu-usuário` e `seu-repositório` e tudo deve funcionar como esperado.

Após fazer essas alterações será possível utilizar o seu repositório `git` novamente.

No material passado como referência existe indicação de outras maneiras de autenticar sua conta que também são consideradas seguras.

### Solução de problemas

Se ao final do processo ao tentar fazer push;pull do repositório e estiver recebendo o erro:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Verifique o endereço remoto da aplicação para acesso via SSH, este valor é fornecido pela interface gráfica do GitHub ao acessar o seu repositório e clicar  no botão *Code*

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor exibido, deve ser igual ao valor do retorno do comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Caso não seja, repetir os passos da configuração do repositório com os valores corretos.

Answer (score -2):

Bom, depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, consegui resolver.

Como foi a minha primeira vez usando o GIT, eu não tenho muita familiaridade com esse tipo de tecnologia, mas, com certeza, **fiz alguma burrice na hora de cadastrar a minha chave SSH na máquina. Resolvi o problema excluindo a chave SSH antiga e cadastrando uma nova.**

Sobre a pergunta, acabei não formulando ela muito bem por conta do cansaço de uma sprint de quase 12hrs de estudos. rs.

**Recorri ao Stackoverflow, pois já tinha cadastrado a chave SSH e anda sim o git me pedia o e-mail e senha quando eu tentava realizar o Push.**

Deixo aqui este relato para quem venha a ter o mesmo tipo de dificuldade.

Pode não ser a melhor solução, mas foi a que resolveu o meu problema e pode ser que resolva o seu também.